# global static function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does the following returns `undefined`?

```
var global_vars = 
{

    countNumOfProperties : 
        function (obj) 
        {
            var count = 0;
            for (var k in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    ++count;
                }
                return count;
            }
        }    
};


var DS =
{
    file_types_lookup : {}
};


global_vars.countNumOfProperties(DS.file_types_lookup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement is inside the loop so is never reached.

```
        for (var k in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                ++count;
            }
            return count;
        }
```

should probably be

```
        for (var k in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
```

That way, each property will be checked before the sum is returned.

As written, the function will return

- `1` to indicate that the first enumerable property is an own property, or
- `0` to indicate that there are no own properties but there are enumerable inherited properties, or
- `undefined` to indicate that there are no enumerable properties `own` or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Because the object has no own properties, so the `for` loop has no iterations that are executed, and no `return` statement gets executed.

I guess you misplaced a `}`:

```
var count = 0;
for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
         ++count;
    }
}
return count;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return count;` statement should be outside of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Observe what happens when you pass it an object that *does* have properties:

```
> global_vars.countNumOfProperties({foo: 1})
1
> global_vars.countNumOfProperties({foo: 1, bar: 2})
1
> global_vars.countNumOfProperties({foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3})
1
```

The problem is that you put the `return` statement inside the loop. It will be executed the first time the loop body executes, returning `1` and ending the loop. However, if the loop body never runs (because there are no properties) it never gets run and the function returns the default value, `undefined`.

You just need to move `return` down by one line, outside the loop.